# how do I resolve this antlr ambiguity?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a 4000 line text file which is parsing slowly, taking perhaps 3 minutes.  I am running the Intellij Antlr plugin.  When I look at the profiler, I see this:

[image]

The time being consumed is the largest of all rules, by a factor of 15 or so. That's ok, the file is full of things I actually don't care about (hence 'trash'). However, the profiler says `words_and_trash` is ambiguous but I don't know why.  Here are the productions in question. (There are many others of course...):

[image]

I have no idea why this is ambiguous. The parser isn't complaining about `so_much_trash` and I don't think `word`, `trash`, and `OPEN_PAREN` overlap.

What's my strategy for solving this ambiguity?

Comment: BTW, please do not post images of code.

Comment: yeah, my work is done on a secure server, I can't copy/paste anything but images.

Answer (score 2):

It's ambiguous because, given your two alternatives for `words_and_trash`, anything that matches the first alternative, could also match the second alternative (that's the definition `ambiguity` in this context).

It appears you might be using a technique common in other grammar tools to handle repetition.  ANTLR can do this like so:

```
words_and_trash: so_much_trash+;
so_much_trash: word
             | trash
             | OPEN_PAREN words_and_trash CLOSE_PAREN
             ;
```

You might also find the following video, useful: [ANTLR4 Intellij Plugin -- Parser Preview, Parse Tree, and Profiling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A2-BquvxMU).  It's by the author of ANTLR, and covers ambiguities.

Comment: thanks Mike.  Does the "+" repetition operator guarantee the input is processed left-to-right?

Comment: I made that change, the ambiguity did not go away though the time dropped by about half.

Comment: The `+` just says that there will be "one of more" of whatever it's applied to (in this case, the `so_much_trash` rule).   All input is processed from in the order it's encountered in the token stream, so I suppose you could consider that "left to right".  If you're referring to associativity, the `assoc=left` is the default, but there's nothing here where associativity would factor in.

Comment: I think I do mean assoc=left.  Thanks!

Comment: If you still have an ambiguity, it would have to be in the alternatives of `so_much_trash`, so we'd need to see the rules for `word` and `trash` to point out specifically what is wrong, but the problem will be input that could match either `word` or `trash`.

Comment: since you're already using IntelliJ, take a look at the video, it should be really helpful in resolving the source of ambiguities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245113/discussion-between-mike-cargal-and-tony-ennis).